# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no pytorch_jni in java.library.path

Tags: java, pytorch, djl

I am trying to load a pytorch model file, `model.pt`, that I trained into my Java Spring Boot application by using the DJL Framework on Windows 11. After adding all the dependencies and writing my `RestController` and running the application I get "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no pytorch_jni in java.library.path"

These are my pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${jna.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.djl.spring/djl-spring-boot-starter-pytorch-auto -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.djl.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>djl-spring-boot-starter-pytorch-auto</artifactId>
            <version>0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.djl.pytorch</groupId>
            <artifactId>pytorch-native-cpu</artifactId>
            <classifier>win-x86_64</classifier>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.djl.pytorch</groupId>
            <artifactId>pytorch-jni</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1-0.21.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.djl.pytorch/pytorch-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ai.djl.pytorch</groupId>
            <artifactId>pytorch-engine</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pytorch/pytorch_java_only -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pytorch</groupId>
            <artifactId>pytorch_java_only</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

and this is my Controller

```
package com.example.MyShroom_backend.controller;

import com.example.MyShroom_backend.dto.ClassifierRequestDto;
import com.example.MyShroom_backend.dto.ClassifierResponseDto;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.pytorch.IValue;
import org.pytorch.Module;
import org.pytorch.Tensor;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/classifier")
public class ClassifierController {

    @PostMapping("/predict")
    public ResponseEntity<?> predict(@RequestBody ClassifierRequestDto dto) {
        // Load the PyTorch model from a file
        Module module = Module.load("path/to/myModels/model.pt");

        // Define the normalization parameters for the ResNet34 model
        float[] mean = new float[]{0.485f, 0.456f, 0.406f};
        float[] std = new float[]{0.229f, 0.224f, 0.225f};

        // Convert the input image to a tensor
        byte[] imageBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dto.getBase64Img());
        Tensor inputTensor = Tensor.fromBlob(imageBytes, new long[]{1, 3, 224, 224});

        float[] inputValues = inputTensor.getDataAsFloatArray();
        // Normalize the input tensor
        for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
            inputValues[i] = (inputValues[i] - mean[i]) / std[i];
        }

        Tensor newInputTensor = Tensor.fromBlob(inputValues,new long[]{1, 3, 224, 224});
        // Make a prediction using the PyTorch model
        IValue output = module.forward(IValue.from(newInputTensor));
        Tensor outputTensor = output.toTensor();
        float[] scores = outputTensor.getDataAsFloatArray();

        // Return the prediction as a JSON string
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ClassifierResponseDto("{\"scores\": " + Arrays.toString(scores) + "}"));
    }

}
```

and the error appears at this line `Module module = Module.load("path/to/myModels/model.pt");`

After I did some digging in my project I found the pytorch_jni.dll file in the `target/classes/lib/` folder and also in the application.jar, so that means that the mvn dependencies generate it but the file has size 0 KB, so even if I try to copy it in one of the `java.library.path` paths it generates another error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\pytorch_jni.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:384) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:228) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:170) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:311) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:281) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2422) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989) ~[na:na]
    at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.SystemDelegate.loadLibrary(SystemDelegate.java:24) ~[nativeloader-0.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:51) ~[nativeloader-0.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:30) ~[nativeloader-0.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.pytorch.NativePeer.<clinit>(NativePeer.java:10) ~[pytorch_java_only-1.13.1.jar:na]
    at org.pytorch.Module.load(Module.java:28) ~[pytorch_java_only-1.13.1.jar:na]
    at org.pytorch.Module.load(Module.java:38) ~[pytorch_java_only-1.13.1.jar:na]
    at com.example.MyShroom_backend.controller.ClassifierController.predict(ClassifierController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:906) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at com.example.MyShroom_backend.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

and this would technically be caused by the .dll file being 64-bit and the JVM being only 32-bit but that is not the case, it's just the fact that the file is empty. I cannot figure why this is, maybe someone more experienced can help me?

Comment: You will need to inspect the maven build system to see how the file is supposed to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few issues in your `pom.xml`:

1. You included `org.pytorch:pytorch_java_only`, this has nothing to do with DJL, and `pytorch_jni.dll` seems related to this library.
2. You djl-springboot package is using 0.20, but your pytorch-engine is using 0.21.0. This may causing dependency mismatch. Please using matching version.